# Distinct on field plus rest of fields from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your assistance with a distinct query. I have the query below that returns all distinct values for the table but I also would like to see the rest of the columns rather than just the distinct column. How could I do this?

I tried several changes but is not working. Working on Oracle and SQL Developer.

```
select distinct field1 from table1
where field2 in ('A','B','C')
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample input and the expected output to clarify what you need?

Comment: How would you determine which values to pick from the table for a particular `field1` when running a distinct query? Should they be maximum values, or what?

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to pick the other values? Here are some options:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( field1, field2, field3 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - Get the first row**:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table1 t
  WHERE  field2 IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Output 1**:

```
    FIELD1 FIELD2     FIELD3
---------- ------ ----------
         1 A               1 
         2 A               1 
         3 B               3
```

**Query 2 - Get the maximum values for `field1`**:

```
SELECT field1,
       MAX( field2 ) AS field2,
       MAX( field3 ) AS field3
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  field2 IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
GROUP BY field1;
```

**Output 2**:

```
    FIELD1 FIELD2     FIELD3
---------- ------ ----------
         1 C               3
         2 C               3 
         3 B               3
```

*Note: the first 2 output rows does not match any row in the original data as the maximum values are taken from different rows.*

**Query 3 - Get the maximum `field2` and the corresponding maximum `field3` values**:

```
SELECT field1,
       MAX( field2 ) AS field2,
       MAX( field3 ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Field2 ) AS field3
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  field2 IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
GROUP BY field1;
```

or

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field2 DESC, field3 DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table1 t
  WHERE  field2 IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

**Output 3**:

```
    FIELD1 FIELD2     FIELD3
---------- ------ ----------
         1 C               1 
         2 C               1 
         3 B               3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

```
select distinct * from table1 where field2 in ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in theory, you cant do what you are thinking. The reason for that is that when you use distinct clause, all the fields listed are considered on the distinct, because one field could assume 2 distinct values, but the other fields for one single value on that field could also assume different values.

Answer (score -1):

If you want one row per `field1` value, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t1.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by field1 order by field1) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
      where field2 in ('A','B','C')
     ) t;
```